# SimpleCart JS Cart Display

Tags: javascript, shopping-cart, cart

I am using [SimpleCart Js](http://simplecartjs.com) and am wondering would it be possible to make it so it does not display the cart part until someone adds something to cart? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a callback, i mean, when click to add a an element, it changes the css of the cart from hidden to visible